# Expresión regular con egrep para obtener la palabra valor_[número]

Tags: linux, grep

Tengo un archivo con este contenido:

```
clave="valor 1" valor 2 valor 3

valor 4

clave="valor 5" valor 6

valor 7
```

y quiero extraer con una expresión regular aquellas palabras que contengan la palabra valor, seguida de un espacio en blanco y un número que no estén entrecomilladas, es decir, solo me valen valor 2, valor 3, valor 4, valor 6 y valor 7. El resto al estar entrecomilladas no me valen. Lo estoy haciendo con el comando egrep de linux, pero me serviría cualquiera que acepte las mismas expresiones.

La expresión que yo he utilizado, y que en PHP funciona correctamente devolviéndome un array con las coincidencias, es esta:

```
[^"]valor\s\d
```

Con el comando grep ó egrep soy incapaz de extraer esos valores.

Comment: Anunciar lo que uno quiere hacer está bien, pero demostrar lo que uno ha intentado hacer está mejor. Y sobre todo... NO NOS GRITES POR FAVOR! Escribir en mayúsculas de manera continuada se considera gritar y pedir ayuda a gritos está bien para salvar la vida de uno (o incluso una vida ajena), pero para un problema de programación, lo veo un poco exagerado. Usa el botón [edit] y añade lo que has intentado de paso que cambias el título a minúsculas :)

Comment: @JoséManuel Creo que yo te hubiera indicado lo mismo, que las mayúsculas representan gritos y que no has puesto tus intentos en la pregunta, lo cual invalida la pregunta según lo estipulado en las normas de este sitio que encontrarás en [ask]. No hace falta ser descortés en tu comentario y el comentario de Benito-B denota cierto sarcasmo y humor, el cual no debes haber comprendido y te ha enojado.  Por favor, pon lo que dices que has intentado para que te ayudemos a corregirlo, pues las preguntas sin código no son válidas tampoco. Lée [example] tambien, gracias.

Comment: @JoséManuel Y creo que tanto Benito-B como yo pretendemos darte respuesta, solo que no se nos permite (o está mal visto por la comunidad) que lo hagamos sin exigirte primero que nos muestres lo que has intentando y que errores tienes a corregir, pues en caso contrario estariamos realizando tareas para ti, no corrigiendote, y tampoco está permitido (aunque muchos lo hacen, ojo, pero también se llevan sus votos negativos al hacerlo). Repasa [ask], [tour] y [example] y tus preguntas serán mejor recibidas.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón del mundo masterguru, y te agredezco tu respuesta, pero hay que cuidar las formas, y los vaciles de algunos espabilados de esta red me irritan mucho. Hay que ser humilde, pero hay mucho niñato subidito. Te indico la expresión que yo hice: 

[^"]valor\s\d 

En PHP funciona correctamente y me devuelve un array con las palabras valor n que no van entrecomilladas. Con el comando egrep ó grep -E soy incapaz de obtenerlo. Gracias

Comment: Gracias por comprenderlo, a ver, si te relees lo que decia Benito-B verás que termina con carita de sonrisa, denotando su humor, pero bueno, dejemos ese tema. En cuanto a tu código que has puesto en el comentario, mejor ponlo en la pregunta editándola de nuevo, para que los demás lo puedan ver, sino solo lo veran los que se lean los comentarios y perderás audiencia y posibles ayudas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```
grep -P '(?<![\S"])(valor\s\d)(?![\S"])' -o nombrearchivo
```

lo cual debería devolverte esto:

```
valor 2
valor 3
valor 4
valor 6
valor 7
```

Las explicaciones de la expresión regular puedes verlas en la casilla derecha de [este enlace](https://regex101.com/r/8GkMK5/1), bajo el título EXPLANATION (no grito, es que está en mayúsculas! :-)).

Y en cuanto al grep, lo que hacemos es decirle que use expresiones regulares compatibles de Perl (PCREs) con el parámetro **-P** y que solo nos muestre las coincidencias con el parámetro **-o**.

Ya nos dirás si te ha funcionado.

Comment: Perfecto masterguru, lo has clavado!!. Muchas GRACIAS ( no grito, es la emoción ;-) ). Educación, humildad y profesionalidad, admirable.

Comment: Bueno, tampoco te creas... cuando veo que la gente se enoja entonces intento remediarlo pues aquí todos somos colaboradores y nadie está por encima de nadie, pero tambien soy de los que digo tonterias y bromeo muchas veces :-D (pero si noto que se lo toman a mal me bajo donde haga falta pues no era nunca mi intención, ni creo que la de nadie de por aquí con experiencia)... Si esta respuesta satisface tu pregunta recuerda aceptarla para que la comunidad lo sepa y así no quede la pregunta pendiente eternamente, gracias!